# How to click an extJs button using its span name

Tags: java, button, selenium, extjs, selenium-webdriver

We have a button in the web application that we are trying to simulate which has a dynamic id. The only identifiable reoccurring element of it is the span label (**Bold in the code**). Is there any method or a locator by which the button can be clicked.

```
<em id="button-1723-btnWrap">

<button id="button-1723-btnEl" type="button" class="x-btn-center" hidefocus="true" role="button" autocomplete="off" style="width: 69px; height: 16px;">

<span id="button-1723-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner" style="width: 69px;">Save</span>

<span id="button-1723-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon x-icn-save">
</span>

</button>

</em>
```

Comment: It would be easier if you can set `itemId` on ExtJS when creating button.

Comment: Use Xpath if  element has dynamic id.

Answer (score 0):

You really should look way to set `itemId` for the button on ExtJS when defining button. Would make things easier.

But if that's not possible. Try something like to get button which contains span with text content `Save`

```
By.xpath("//button[span='Save']")
```

You can get span inside any button with text content `Save`

```
By.xpath("//button/span[text()='Save']")
```

Comment: @ ikettu: Thanks for the help, But unfortunately it didn't work out for me!

Comment: I hope you can find proper xpath. You can quickly test different variations on for example http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath

Comment: Edited. Added another variant to test.

Comment: Is this what you needed, or do you need further help?